# How do you configure the Apache httpcore5 java HttpAsyncServer to use TLS on its listening port?

Tags: java, ssl, https

When using the apache httpcore5 java library to implement an HTTP server I can not find the proper idiom for rigging the socket to use TLS.

Under the older httpcore version 4.x I could

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keyStore.load(keystoreStream, keystorePassword.toCharArray());

KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(keyStore, keyPassword.toCharArray());

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sc. init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
ServerSocket sSock = sc.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(port);
```

and then accept connections from that server socket and `bind()` those sockets to a `DefaultHttpServerConnection` and `handleRequest()` in a loop.

I have not yet found an example of how to write a TLS-capable server using the httpcore5 framework.

Answer (score 0):

After some rummaging around I found `H2ServerBootstrap.setTlsStrategy()` and used it like this:

```
SSLContext ctx = buildAppSSLContext();
bootstrap.setTlsStrategy(new BasicServerTlsStrategy(ctx, new FixedPortStrategy(new int[]{port})));
```